# "Sorry, no data for this metric" Android Developers Console (What does this mean?)

Tags: android, google-analytics, console, installation

I uploaded an app about 19 hours ago and it doesn't have any number under installs (not even 0).
It also says in the statistics, "Sorry, no data for this metric".

What does "Sorry, no data for this metric" mean in the Android Developers Console?

Does it mean that I have to wait longer for Google process my app's analytics? Or does it mean that I have no installs?

[This](http://code2care.org/pages/sorry,-no-data-for-this-metric-android-statistics/) is what I got from the internet. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just wait a day or so. I'm not sure on the update interval, but it will take at least a day for an update.

Comment: I'll let you know when it does. So you're sure about this?

Comment: Ok yeah I installed it myself just to see. It says installs: 1/1 now. So the analytics don't show up if there isn't any activity either.

Comment: Learn something new everyday!:)